# Program using memory segment, waits for lock to have acces to data segment(basic)

Tags: c, sleep, shared-memory

I must say i know about semaphors but i dont know how to use them yet. So the thing is I pass  the controll to my  data segment when the `int lock` gets a specific value, how could i make my code work cause at this point it freezes and I can't understand why...

s.c(server) - to be runned first

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "st.h"

int main(){
    int shmid,i;
    int w =1;
    struct msg* m;
    shmid = shmget(1271,sizeof(struct msg), IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0600);

    if(shmid == -1){
        perror("~~~Shmid");
        exit(1);
    }   
    m = shmat(shmid,0,0);
    printf("segment attached to structure");

    do{
    printf("waiting...");
    sleep(1);
    }while(m->lock != 1);

    if(m->lock == 1)
    printf("lock open!");

    shmdt(m);
return 0;
}
```

c.c(client)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2)
        perror("~~~ ./c [file name]");
        exit(1);
    int shmid;
    struct msg* m;
    shmid = shmget(1271,0,0);

    if(shmid == -1){
        perror("~~~Shmid");
        exit(1);
    }   
    m = shmat(shmid,0,0);

    m->f = *argv[1];
    m->lock = 1;

    shmdt(m);
return 0;
}
```

st.h

```
struct msg{
    char f[50];
    int lock;   
};
```

Comment: Also check for failure of shmat: 

`m = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0); if (m == (char *)(-1)) perror("~~~Shmat"); `

Comment: but why would it be diferent? since i remove ipc everytime after fail use of server and i get error when i don't

Comment: The call can fail and not be an error. Also, the second argument needs to be a pointer else you overwrite the begining of your segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies at the beginning of your client's code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2)
        perror("~~~ ./c [file name]");
        exit(1);
    int shmid;
    ...
```

You should have put the `perror()` and `exit()` statements inside a block of curly braces.

In your current code the exit statement is always called and your client terminates without attaching to the memory block and changing the value of the lock.

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0); // note pointer
if (data == (char *)(-1))
    perror("shmat");
```

Comment: C does implicit integer to pointer conversion and using `NULL`, `0`, or `(void *)0` would give the same result, although some compilers may complain about the implicit conversion.